# How do I find the intercept between $y=c$ and $y=\frac{x}{e^x}$ where $0\leq c\leq \frac 1e$?

Tags: functions, exponential-function

How do I find the intercept between $y=c$  and $y=\frac{x}{e^x}$ where $0\leq c\leq \frac 1e$?

Using graphical software, I am able to find intercept when e.g. $c=0.2$. How do I solve it non-graphically?

Comment: Solve $c=\frac{x}{e^x}$ ? However you will probably need the Lambert W function to get an "explicit" solution...

Comment: $x=ce^x$ has no closed form solution.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a numerical solution. Newton's Method will probably work.

Let $f(x)=xe^{-x}-c$. Then $f'(x)=e^{-x}-xe^{-x}=(1-x)e^{-x}$

For a given $x_n$, let $x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{x_ne^{-x_n}-c}{(1-x_n)e^{-x_n)}}$

Rearranging:

$x_{n+1}=\frac{ce^{x_n}-x_n^2}{(1-x_n)}$. Find a good $x_0$, then iterate.

$f''(x)=-e^{-x}-e^{-x}+xe^{-x}=(x-2)e^{-x}$

Finding a zero of the Taylor polynomial to second order

$-c+x-(x^2)=0$

Set
$x_0=\frac{-1+\sqrt{1-4c}}{-2}$

That alone might be decent accuracy, iterations should converge quickly.

Answer (score 0):

The equation can be written as $\,-xe^{-x}=-c\,$, and has closed form solutions in terms of the [Lambert W](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) function. Comparing with the definition $W(z)=w \iff \,w e^w=z\,$  it follows that:

$$
-x = W\left(-c\right) \;\;\;\;\iff\;\;\;\; x = -W\left(-c\right)
$$

The Lambert $W$ function is [multivalued](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivalued_function), and for $\,0\leq c\leq \frac 1e$ $\iff -\frac{1}{e} \le -c \le 0\,$ the two real solutions are $-W_0(-c)$ and $\,-W_{-1}(-c)\,$.